# How to scale my stratus application?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, adobe, soundcloud-stratus

Stratus is currently in beta !

So, if I create a simple app with stratus tecnology and I get millions of users, then how can I scale the application ?

How chatroulette have resolved the scaling issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stratus itself is [probably] a redundant distributed system of Adobe-owned servers accepting connections so rapidly that it is not an issue at all. On top of that, remember that Stratus simply distributes peer identifiers, and all other communication that is any bandwidth-hungry is peer-to-peer, which obviously does not suffer from scaling problems at all.

chatroulette use an array of Red5 servers that stream video in case peers cannot communicate directly (behind firewall/NAT etc), and they HAVE used a PHP/MySQL database backend for peer discovery (Stratus does not discover peers, it simply shares them on demand). I say "HAVE" because that's what it was at a very early point in time, they would be wise to not do PHP/MySQL now, because that would be a suicide with their amount of traffic.

**UPDATE**
It seems I was talking out of my a$$ when mentioning chatroulette using Red5. I have no evidence whatsoever of the fact, and may have remembered something wrong or confused it with some other service. I do have evidence it used FMS 3.5.2 as of the time of writing.

Comment: chatroulette use Red5 ? Where have you read this ?
Thanks ^_^

Comment: I think I was wrong, but I can see that it uses Flash Media Server 3.5.2 now. That is however not the evidence that it does not use Red5.

Comment: mmm How can you see that chatroulette use FMS ?

Comment: I used Wireshark to sniff on RTMP traffic. When first initating RTMP connection, FMS returns an identification string to the connecting client. Then you know it is in fact FMS at the other end. In case with chatroulette.com, it said "FMS 3,5,2".